# OpenAI API: How do I prevent the OpenAI model from answering questions that are outside the scope I set?

Tags: android, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am currently in the process of developing an Android application that requires access to information specifically related to the IT sector or medical sector. For that, I use the OpenAI API in the app.

However, I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively utilize the OpenAI API to ensure it responds only to queries related to a particular sector.

Any idea how I can achieve this with the OpenAI API using Python?

Answer (score 1):

**The best way to achieve this is to customize the system message.** The system message can be used to specify the persona used by the model in its replies, as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/prompt-engineering/tactic-ask-the-model-to-adopt-a-persona).

The default system message is the following:

> You are a helpful assistant.

You need to customize it as follows:

> You are a helpful assistant, answering questions only about the IT
> sector or medical sector. For all other questions that are out of the
> scope of these two sectors, please respond politely that the question
> is out of your scope. In this case, do not answer it.

In Python, the following code is what you're looking for:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant, answering questions only about the IT sector or medical sector. For all other questions that are out of the scope of these two sectors, please respond politely that the question is out of your scope. In this case, do not answer it."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello world!"},
  ]
)
```